# Can I force Linux to write data at the start of a file system?

Tags: partitioning, dd, luks, copy, inode

**TLDR;**

Is there a command to force Linux to write a file (for example a PDF file, MP3, anything really) at the start of a file system ? I don't thing that `# dd` does the trick, because the inode table needs to be updated too after copying this file.

**The full story**

I use a LUKS encrypted drive with plausible deniability. Meaning, I have a 500G partition with 20G of decoy data at the beginning of the partition. Further on that partition I have a hidden LUKS container, with a 25G offset and a detached header. I am using this for quite some years now, it works fine.

How am I sure that the 20G of decoy data are at the start of the partition ? Well, I first created a 20G partition, copied the decoy data to it, and then I increased its size to 500G.

Now I'd like to refresh those 20G of decoy data, e.g. I'd like to delete the 20G of data, and copy some 20G of new data. Of course I need to be sure that the copy operation doesn't mess with the hidden container that's further on the partition. Meaning that I need to find a way to ensure that the data copied to the partition will be in the first 20G of the partition.

Is there a way to do that ? And if yes, will it work on both HDDs and SSDs ?

**[UPDATE]**

An idea inspired by @TomYan's comment : if I delete the 500G partition, re-create a 20 GB partition, fill it with decoy data, and then increase that new 20GB partition to 500G, will my hidden LUKS container starting at 25G remain unscathed ?

Comment: Having *all* of your data at the start of the partition sounds more suspicious than plausible deniability, you would expect data to be scattered around the partition rather than focused in one area. Having it all focused in one area would be odd and would look intentional to anyone who worked in computing.

Comment: `Well, I first created a 20G partition, copied the decoy data to it, and then I increased its size to 500G.` It's quite confusing to be frank. If you then use the 500G partition without offsetting, then your decoy data would have been overwritten by your non-decoy data. Can you give a proper/exact layout?

Comment: Or have you been talking about a filesystem after all? So you want to (re-)create a *file* of 20G in a *filesystem* and make sure that the data of the *file* locates at the (more or less) beginning of the partition?

Comment: I wonder if `conv=notrunc` of `dd` does the job. My *guess* is it will likely do if it's some "simpler" filesystem like ext4. (SSD optimizations in the filesystem driver, if any, might intervene. They might write to different LBAs whenever possible. Purely my wild guess though.)

Comment: @Mokubai :nothing suspicious. To enforce plausible deniability both the outer and the inner volume are LUKS encrypted. After encrypting the outer volume and before creating the inner one, I wiped the empty spaces, so at rest my 500G contains 500G of scrambled data.

Comment: @TomYan `If you then use the 500G partition without offsetting` : the inner LUKS container has an offset of course (25G), I updated my post to clarify this. `So you want to (re-)create a file of 20G in a filesystem` : Yes, exactly. Or more precisely I want to replace the various existing files (20G in total) by another set of 20GB files, and make sure the new files are all written at the start of the 500G filesystem

Comment: `the inner LUKS container has an offset of course (25G)` I don't think you really mean that. It sounds to me what you really mean is, you "pre-occupy" the more-or-less-beginning 20G of a partition/LUKS container through a filesystem on it. Offset would mean the 20G is not involved in the partition/LUKS container or at least the filesystem that you write the non-decoy data to (which would make things easy). `Or more precisely I want to replace the various existing files (20G in total) by another set of 20GB files` Yeah I bet that too. Anyway, I personally don't know any concrete way to do that.